# Visual C#, unable to use my struct as a property

Tags: c#, struct, properties, controls

I made a user control which contains several self-made properties. When I tried to set the property type to build-in structures such as Point or Size, it showed up fine!

```
public Point myProperty { get; set; }
```

[image]

But when I set it to my own struct, it doesn't work! It becomes **PriceInput.PriceInput+myStruct** (PriceInput is the namespace)

[image]

myStruct looks like

```
    public struct myStruct
    {
        public int A {get;set;}
        public int B {get;set;}
        public int C {get;set;}
        public int D {get;set;}
    }
```

Why!? What do I miss!? Thank you very very much for your help!

Comment: Override ToString

Comment: What is the declaration of myStruct on the class you are using?  public and getter/setter?

Comment: It IS public and both getter and setter.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `ToString` if you want a meaningful output:

```
public struct myStruct
{
    public int A {get;set;}
    public int B {get;set;}
    public int C {get;set;}
    public int D {get;set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{A}:{B}:{C}:{D}";
    }
}
```

[`Object.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) just returns the the fully qualified name of the object's type.

Comment: I'm using Ultimate 2013. Seems like it don't support $! Would you please be so kind and teach me a way I could use please!? Thanks!

Comment: @PiggyChu: if you can't use it, use: `return String.Join(":", new[]{A, B, C, D});` or `return String.Format("{0}:{0}:{0}:{0}", A, B, C, D);` or `return A + ":" + B + ":" + C + ":" + D;` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: I tried, it just return "0:0:0:0". It still didn't have a plus sign in front of it where I could expand it and see its members (A,B,C,D), just like in the Point example I could see X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Per default every class or struct will just print out its own name within any output, be it the console or whatever. In your case this is `PriceInput.PriceInput+myStruct`. That´s because the runtime has no knowledge on what to print. Imagine you´d have more properties in your struct. Should all go the output? Or just a few ones? How should they be formatted? That´s why the runtime decides to not to guess and simply prints out the class`/structs name.

To avoid this (and that´s what `Point` also does), override the `ToString`-method in your struct:

```
public struct myStruct
{
    public override string  ToString()
    {
        return "Whatever";
    }
}
```

If you do not override this method, you get the base-implementation from `object`, which just returns the type-name as shown above.

Comment: I tried, but it REALLY returns whatever I type in there! Could you please teach me how to make it like the Point structure so I can expand it and see its members please!? In my case it will be A,B,C,D. Thanks!

Comment: Is there no expand-button next to your `myProperty`? That´s indeed weird. That shouldn´t depend at all on how the instance is printed within the cell to the right.

Comment: And that's what's bothering me! Could you please point me to the right direction please!?